# How to avoid function as instance members in controller's scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angularJS 1.3, In the below code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var app = angular.module("sample", []);
                app.controller("emp", function(){
                        this.Name = "jag";
                        this.sal = "4500";
                        this.getAnnualSal = function(){
                            return (this.sal) * 12;
                        }
                    });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="sample">
            <div ng-controller="emp as o">
                Hello {{o.Name}}, your annual salary is {{o.getAnnualSal()}}

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

It looks weird to keep function(`getAnnualSal`) as controller instance member.
Because, every controller instance of `emp` has its own `getAnnualSal`.

`emp` controller instance scope looks like this:

[image]

Does it make sense to maintain function(`getAnnualSal`) as prototype members? If yes, please provide the syntax.

Comment: You will rarely declare a class for the controller. So don't worry about prototypes. Specially when only one instance will exist at a time. But yes, you can freely do it.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli  want the syntax for it

Comment: Writing the answer...

Comment: browsers are allowed to recycle identical functions, so a prototype might not save as much as expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alternative is to declare your controller as a separate class. AngularJS does not provide a special syntax for this, so you can...

```
function MyController() {
    this.Name = "jag";
    this.sal = "4500";
} 
MyController.prototype.getAnnualSal = function(){
    return (this.sal) * 12;
}
var app = angular.module("sample", []);
app.controller("emp", MyController);
```

If you want to use custom injections (e.g. `$scope`, `$rootScope`, ...), you can:

```
function MyController($scope) { ... all the former code ... }
...
var app = angular.module("sample", []);
app.controller("emp", ['$scope', MyController]);
```

For doubts related to injection, please refer the official tutorial or docs (e.g. `$provide`). The only difference is using an anonymous function or a named function (which always behaves as a constructor).

Comment: But `MyController` is global contoller used in pre 1.3 angularjs

Comment: I only changed slightly the syntax you provided.

Comment: I am passing explicitly the reference to the controller class, to the .controller call. It is **not** global since being global means forcing angular to look on `window` for the reference, which i am NOT doing, but passing the reference directly

Comment: In your second approach, Do we need to pass `$scope` to function `getAnnualSal`? I mean `MyController.prototype.getAnnualSal = function($scope){..}`

Comment: No you dont. And no, you shouldn't. Specially if the function will be used in the templates: no `$scope` object, with any name, is available there.

Comment: If you need a reference to the scope, save it as member in `this`, and use it in your methods (unless the methods are created for an instance instead of the prototype).

Comment: [Code](https://github.com/shamhub/angularjs/blob/master/Lec2_Controller/file2.html) is not working with your second approach

Comment: Becuase getAnnualSal() does not belong to the scope. You should call it as o.getAnnualSal(), where o is an alias of your controller (MyController as o)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083240/controller-inheritance-vs-scope-inheritance further on this.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use directive actually instead of a sole controller.  If you think about it,

1. What would you do if your controller scope needs dom manipulation?
2. What if you need multiple instances of this controller as you mentioned?
3. Then you need a html template?

One thing you should do though in general is to assign this to a var on top of the scope so you can reference later.

```
app.controller("emp", function(){
                        var vm = this;
                        this.Name = "jag";
                        this.sal = "4500";
                        this.getAnnualSal = function(){
                            return (vm.sal) * 12;
                        }
                    });
```